# How to access and extract data in App Script that is not bound to the code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-forms, data-extraction

I am working on a script that is standalone. It collects its baseline data from a google sheet bound to a form. In the form submission, excel documents are uploaded. While I can access the link for the excel document(google downloads the excel into your drive upon submission and inserts the drive link into the google response sheet), I am having difficulty looking into and extracting anything (exact cell values, ranges, indexes, etc) from the excel doc.

I have tried using various functions from the sheets and spreadsheets classes and continue to get errors. Some suggestions I've found say the excel document needs to be converted into a google sheet before the app script can access it, or that app script won't allow you to work with such a document if it is not bound to your script (since that allows you to activate it)(I can't bind the excel doc because it changes upon every new submission of the form).

Has anyone ever compiled a similar code and figured out how to access an unbound, non-google doc?

Let me know if you need error codes or script snippets. I just wasn't sure if this was a syntax problem or a google suite trick spot that needed extra code that I probably haven't found cause I'm new to this platform.

Comment: "Let me know if you need error codes or script snippets" Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Has anyone ever compiled a similar code and figured out how to access an unbound, non-google doc?

Scripts in Google Apps Script aren't "compiled" by the script writer in the sense that it's done when developing something in other platforms.

To get data from a file hosted in Google Drive, first the script should get that file by using the *Drive Service* (`Class DriveApp`) or the *Drive Advanced Service*.

The next part depends pretty much on the Excel file format. If it's an `xlsx` file, then usually the most convenient is to convert the file into an Google spreadsheet as this will make possible to use the *Spreadsheet Service* (Class `SpreadsheetApp`) to read the data from it.

If you don't want to convert it to a Google spreadsheet file, or it can't be converted the the "basic" means because it's using an incompatible format (like a `xls` file format), then you will need to use an library or an external service to parse the Excel file content.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getalldataonsheet() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');//you provide id
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('sheetname');//you provide sheet namme
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vs=rg.getValues();//2d array
  return vs;//this return 2d array
}
```

There are restrictions for passing parameters in [client to server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: The other hitch is since a new excel doc is uploaded with every submission I also don't have access to the sheet name. I know that it is always the same as the doc name (minus the extension of course) but it would be something I would have to fetch. So far I can only find functions that get data based on the name (like you showed above) but none that retrieve the name.

Comment: Try `var name=docname.split('.')[0]` and actually there are a lot of ways of getting substrings from strings. This is the [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7) I use

Comment: Also if you know that there is always only 1 sheet then you could use `ss.getSheets()[0];`

Comment: ok so i tried the code with the .getSheet line instead of the getSheetByName and I got this error.   "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id (and then the appropriate id was listed)". do you know what this means?

Comment: Yes.  Well as you might well know spelling counts in programming.  It is ss.getSheets()[0];

Comment: If you are going ask questions about your coding then you need to post your code in the question.

Comment: sorry i was using short hand since that wasnt the line that threw the error this one was: 'const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);'  ssId is a string variable I previously in the code extracted and have verified that is did so appropriately.

Comment: again it you wish to ask question about code then paste your code into a question.

Comment: Copy/Paste
Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: <code>const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);<code>     I have now tried 2 different directed methods to "properly" share code and none have worked so i hope reading it like normal text can work for you

Comment: Have you read my last comment?Checkout the format code

Comment: @KaylaMcC Usually *good* questions get the answer that the OP is looking for faster than "other" questions. It could take patience and practice to make *good* questions specially when they are from a new field/discipline/"platform".